# Replace the text between two strings using JS RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have one string and I want to update the value between two comments in that string.

I'm not sure how I can do that using RegEx

```
var string = "/* ANIMATION START */ new string should be added here /* ANIMATION END */";
```

I know what I should use `.replace()` with `RegEx`, but I don't know to create the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the **[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/VsC7iF/1)** you will need to use:

```
\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/([\w\s]+)\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/
```

**Demo:**

This is **[a sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/qhasmfnq/)** you need to use to replace the text and get the desired output:

```js
var string = "/* ANIMATION START */ new string should be added here /* ANIMATION END */";
var regex = /(\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/)([\w\s]+)(\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/)/ig; 
string = string.replace(regex, "$1 ###ADDED TEXT### $3");
console.log(string);
```

We just need to use two other matching groups respectively for the `ANIMATION START` and `ANIMATION END` parts, so we can reuse them in the replacement string.

Comment: Thank this works perferect in the test! Just have one error when I add this to JS `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

`var string = "/* ANIMATION START */ new string should be added here /* ANIMATION END */";

var regex = \/\*[\w\s]+\*\/([\w\s]+)\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/;

string = string.replace(regex, "Some cool codee!!!");`

Comment: @DenisLapiLapadatovic Well you got this exception because the regex isn't correct you need to create it using `RegExp` constructor or by wrapping it between two `/`, FYI : using the regex in a replace call will replace the whole regex.

Comment: @DenisLapiLapadatovic That's because we didn't included special characters, like `=`, [this is the **updated Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/VsC7iF/2), that works perfectly.

Comment: I used this exprerssion and still remove the comments instead of only text inside the comments `var regex = /(\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/)([\w=\-"';_\s]+)(\/\*[\w\s]+\*\/)/ig;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153073/discussion-between-denis-lapi-lapadatovic-and-chsdk).

Answer (score -1):

There are 3 parts:

"(\[\s\S]|[^"])*" for matching double quoted strings.

'(\[\s\S]|[^'])*' for matching single quoted strings.

(//.*|/*[\s\S]*?*/) for matching both single line and multiline comments.

The replace function check if the matched string is a comment. If it's not, don't replace. If it is, replace " and '.

```
function t_replace(data){
    var re = /"(\\[\s\S]|[^"])*"|'(\\[\s\S]|[^'])*'|(\/\/.*|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)/g;
    return data.replace(re, function(all, strDouble, strSingle, comment) {
        if (comment) {
            return all.replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
        }
        return all;
    });
}
```